# Wordpress read post data from a form and create new post programmatically

Tags: wordpress

I have created a HTML form and the data will be submitted to a wordpress plugin to create new post programmatically. But, how can I call this wordpress plugin by URL, so that I can define the URL for the `form` action tag?

The wordpress plugin of create new post programmatically can refer to [here](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/02/09/programmatically-creating-posts-in-wordpress/).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do a custom PHP file to handle the form  and use [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to create a new post?

Plugins normally use nonces or other methods to prevent unauthorized users to access them directly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I would like to know how can I call a custom wordpress plugin by access a URL?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but you can try `plugins_url()` to fetch the URL.